# Eclipse - increase size of 'Export destination' dropdown history

Tags: eclipse, jar, export

I'm currently running Luna but have also come across this frustration wth older versions, e.g. Kepler, Juno etc.

When doing an export of a runnable JAR, the second dropdown box (Export destination) in the 'Runnable JAR File Export' wizard seems only to cache a limited history of previously chosen destinations -- five or six.

I am regularly doing maintenance work on 8 or 9 different projects and, as I export one project (lets call it 'H'), the export destination for another project (lets call it 'G') is pruned from the dropdown. When I later come back to work on 'G' and export it, I have to re-enter the destination all over again (yes, I know, aww diddums !).

It would just be nice to set a slightly higher limit (say a dozen) on the size of the dropdown history.

Can this be done by altering the Eclipse config ? Or can I get round it another way ?

Thanks for any replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum size of this list is fixed at 5 in the code (constant `COMBO_HISTORY_LENGTH` in `org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.WizardDataTransferPage` which is the base class for the `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.jarpackagerfat.FatJarPackageWizardPage` which provides the Runnable Jar export wizard page).

Comment: I decided to post this in the Eclipse Bugzilla as a suggested enhancement (#458524). Not sure if it will be taken seriously !

Comment: Eclipse bug #458524 was accepted and resolved. Status is now VERIFIED FIXED and will be available in Eclipse 4.5 builds (i.e. Mars).